# Mock Base service in Angular Unit test using Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have Component in Angular 7 which has service as constructor parameter.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'cc-schedule-list',
  templateUrl: './schedule-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule-list.component.scss']
 })
export class ScheduleListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public accountActivityService: AccountActivityService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**BaseService**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaseService {

  public commonHeaders: CommonHeaderModel;
  public legacyData: any;

  constructor(
    public httpClient: HttpClient,
    public appService: AppService
  ) {
      this.legacyData = this.appService.getDataFromLegacy();

      this.commonHeaders = {
        'sourceRequestID': 'KBB',
        'uuid': this.legacyData.UUID,
      };
  }

  getData(url: string, serviceHeaders: any, params?: any) {
    const headers = {...this.commonHeaders, ...serviceHeaders};
    return this.httpClient.get(url, {headers: headers, params: params});
  }
}
```

**AccountActivityService**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountActivityService {

  constructor(public base: BaseService) {
  }

  /**
   * getPendingPayments Function gets the all the pending payment transactions
   *
   * @returns All transactions on the account
   */
  getPendingPayments(electronicCardIdentifier, payeeAccountIdentifier) {
    return null; //return null at present
  }
}
```

**ScheduleListComponent.spec file**

```
describe('ScheduleListComponent',  () => {
  let component: ScheduleListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ScheduleListComponent>;
  let injector: any;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  let accountActivityService: MockAccountActivityService;

/** Mock Account Activity Service  ***/
  class MockAccountActivityService extends AccountActivityService {

   getPendingPayments() {
      return null;
    }
  }


  beforeEach( (() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ScheduleListComponent],
      imports: [
       ...
      ],
      providers: [ UserUtilService, { provide: AccountActivityService, useClass: MockAccountActivityService}],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
   .compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ScheduleListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    accountActivityService = debugElement.injector.get(MockAccountActivityService);

   }));

  it('should create',  () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

 });
```

I am always getting this error 
***Angular testing Cannot read property 'UIID' of undefined or null reference.

May be my ScheduleListComponent has not taking MockAccountActivityServiceas constructor parameter.Kindly help me here

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints and see where it fails? It would also help if you have a stackblitz with these code files, so that we can help easier.

Comment: Why do you create a MockBaseService in the test of the component, since the component doesn't have any dependency on BaseService? And why don't you use jasmine to create mock objects?

Comment: MockBaseService is just created for testing purpose since i am getting error so I did.

Comment: And what's the testing purpose? Why do you think it's necessary to have a mock base service to test a component that doesn't depend on BaseService?

Comment: Ok I have removed MockBaseService from spec file

Comment: `'uuid': this.legacyData.UUID,` is where UUID property is referenced. Does `AppService#getDataFromLegacy` return a promise, an observable or...?

Comment: That's concern here do I have mock that service as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing the spec files of the component you do not need to include the AccountActivityService, because you are testing the component and not the Service.

You can just mock your service doing: `{ provide: AccountActivityService, useValue: {}}`

Try doing this:

**ScheduleListComponent.spec file**

```
describe('ScheduleListComponent',  () => {
  let component: ScheduleListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ScheduleListComponent>;


  beforeEach( (() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ScheduleListComponent],
      imports: [
       ...
      ],
      providers: [ UserUtilService, { provide: AccountActivityService, useValue:{}}],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
   .compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ScheduleListComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;

   }));

  it('should create',  () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
  });

 });
```

Try if this works.